# when i type in the url home.php it opens, i want to prevent this action except if the user logged in

Tags: php

When a user types in the address bar the `home.php` URL, it opens and displays the home page.

I want to prevent users from accessing the home page unless they are logged in.

Below is what I've tried:

```
<?php

if ( isset( $_POST['btn_submit'] ) ) {
    $password = $_POST['txt_pass'];
    if ( $password == '123' ) {
        header( "Location: home.php" ); //home.php
    } else {
        header( "location: index.php" );
    }
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: so when a user is logged in use session/cookie and check if that session/cookie exists. if no - don't let the user open the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP function [defined](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) to limit access to a page if a variable isn't set.

eg

```
<?php defined('userstatus') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
rest of your code here
```

Use this in your home.php and look for a variable you've got in a session or passed to the page.

Comment: is it better to use a constant or just simple session? never used a constant in such way.

Comment: If you're already storing it in a session.

if (isset($_SESSION['errors']))
{
    //Do stuff
} else {
exit('No direct script access allowed');
}

Comment: Oh well, I believe that session or cookie is always created after login, so you can just always use session without anything else.

Comment: @Danielius code could exist elsewhere to set a session without a user being logged in.

EG a session variable could be used to pass an error message or track something else on site. Always better check for things as explicitly as possible.

Comment: well, I have used this code and it blocks me to enter even when I type the password.

Comment: Which file did you put the code in?

Did you change the variable you are checking for to one you actually have set?

Comment: This code would go in any file you wanted to prevent direct access to.

In this case it would need to check for the right session variable, and the code would be in home.php  

I think your original post is lacking a lot of detail on what code is in what files.

Comment: I understood, I put this code defined('userstatus') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); in home.php , and it prevents me from viewing the page even when the password is correct, I am new to php and it's a simple script can you see it in anydesk or teamviewer to help me?

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere.

1. Are you storing $userstatus in a session variable before this page loads?
2. If you are, you would read it as $_SESSION['userstatus'])

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
   session_start();
   if(isset($_POST['btn_submit'] || !$_SESSION['userlogin']))
   {
       $password=$_POST['txt_pass'];
       if($password=='123')
       {           
           $_SESSION['userlogin'] = true;
           header("Location: home.php"); //home.php
       }else{
           header("location: index.php");
       }

   }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a sessions and if the user login it's be:

```
$_SESSION["user"] = "true" ;
```

your code will be like :

```
<?php
if($_SESSION["user"] = "true"){    
   if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']))    
   {           
       $password=$_POST['txt_pass'];           
       if($password=='123')          
       {             
           header("Location: home.php"); //home.php          
       }    
else {               
    header("location: index.php");          
     }    
   }    
}    
else {    
   header("/");    
}     
?>
```